# SQL: how to select result of joined tables with limit based on main table rows quantity?

Tags: sql

I have a table, movies.

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
```

And I have another table, genres.

```
+----+------+----------+
| id | name | movie_id |
+----+------+----------+
```

Guess, that every movie record have 3 genre records binded by movie_id.
I need to get 10 movie records with ALL genre records joined.

My query is:

```
select *
from movies
left join genres on movies.id = genres.movie_id
limit 10;
```

Result is 10 rows, but I want to get 10 movie rows with ALL genre rows joined = 30 rows.

What query should be?

Comment: What do you get whenever replace the order of the tables within the statement and remove the limit clause?

Answer (score 0):

Using `GROUP BY` you can retrieve one row pre movie with concatinated genres:

```
select movies.id, movies.name, GROUP_CONCAT(genres.name) genres
from movies
left join genres on movies.id = genres.movie_id
group by movies.id, movies.name
limit 10;
```

[SQL group by fiddle](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/46accb713adc794f7166b5ab7565a037/)

Answer (score 0):

you can select only 10 movies in a subquery:

```
select * from
(select * from movies limit 10) movies1
left join genres on movies1.id = genres.movie_id
```